# Ajax Crawling on Google App Engine - Does HtmlUnit work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, seo, htmlunit

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/html-snapshot.html

Does HtmlUnit work on AppEngine? If not, are there any other ways to make my GWT app crawlable by search engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A patch for HtmlUnit to work on GAE is in progress.  HtmlUnit's bug tracker [issue 2962074](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2962074&group_id=47038&atid=448269) discusses making HtmlUnit work on GAE, and provides a preliminary patch for accomplishing this.

Comment: How do I apply the patch? I see a .diff file.

Comment: You can use the `patch` tool if you are using Linux or a similar environment.  For details, consult the `patch` manpage.  Or ask Google.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work on the last GAE version (even after patch applying) to check the post 
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/28a9f9737b1b26b5