# app engine support for HtmlUnit

Tags: java, google-app-engine, htmlunit

I'm trying to use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to get DOM of webpages.  However, when I try to run this code on app engine development server (using the eclipse plugin):

```
WebClient wc=new WebClient();
HtmlPage page1= wc.getPage("http://ww.google.com/");
```

I get this exception:

```
java.net.URLStreamHandler is a restricted class.
```

Is it not possible to use HtmlUnit on app engine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax Crawling on Google App Engine - Does HtmlUnit work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285181/ajax-crawling-on-google-app-engine-does-htmlunit-work)

Answer (score 1):

No, HtmlUnit will not work in the app engine sandbox at this time.

However, a patch for HtmlUnit to work on GAE is in progress.  HtmlUnit's bug tracker [issue 2962074](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2962074&group_id=47038&atid=448269) discusses making HtmlUnit work on GAE, and provides a preliminary patch for accomplishing this.

Comment: I have ead this....but i can't understand how to apply that patch...They have submitted .diff files

Answer (score 0):

I am under the impression that HtmlUnit 2.8 should work.

What version do you use?

Comment: im using HtmlUnit 2.8 but still im facing same problem.

im unable to understand Sourceforge solution. and please add me on msn . my id is usman000000@hotmail.com

Comment: Please post your minimal app to htmlunit user list, others can help